# How to evenly distribute growth to each month?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Assume my Dec'2020 revenue is 1000. My total 2021 revenue forecast is 15000.
I turned this into a monthly revenue increase evenly distributing the growth.

I set every month equals to their previous month PLUS a number(currently blank) throughout the 2021.
Then I have a SUM() formula to total every month of 2021.
I would then use goal seek to set the SUM to 15000 and change the value of the "number".

[Results look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyAWM.png)

This has produced the desire result.

However, I am wondering if there's a faster way to do this? I would need this in a formula that I can simply drag over and get the results.

I have tried PMT formula with no luck.

Comment: Depending on what you are forecasting, I would consider if distributing the values evenly over the months is appropriate. Revenue for a lot of businesses tends to vary due to seasonal factors. If your revenue is influenced by seasonality I would consider distributing the volume equal to the season index for each month. I know that is a departure from what you are looking for here - just a potential upgrade to forecast

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you after correctly, but here is my attempt:

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **Rev_Fcst** being the forecast revenue for the next year which is `15,000` in your example;
- **Rev_Mth0** being the starting revenue of Month zero which is `1,000` in your case;
- **Rev_Growth** being a dollar value of monthly revenue growth, and in your assumption this figure is fixed across the 12 months.

Suppose your data is in Column `A:M` being the 13 months from Dec-2020 to Dec-2021,

Use this formula to calculate **Rev_Growth**:

```
=(Rev_Fcst-Rev_Mth0*COLUMNS($A$1:$M$1))/SUMPRODUCT(ROW($1:$12))
```

Suppose the revenue of Month Zero Dec-2020 is in Cell `A2`, then in Cell `B2` enter the following formula, then drag it across all the way to Month Dec-2021.

```
=A2+Rev_Growth
```

See below demonstration:

[image: Demo]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)